# Java Garbage Collection and null

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a following piece of code:

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  //  WeakReference<List> wr = new WeakReference<List>(list);
    System.out.println(" before tot memory... " +  Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println(" before free memory... " +  Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    for(int i =0; i<100; i++)
    list.add(new String("hello"));
    //System.gc();
    list = null; //forcefully end its life expectancy
    System.out.println(" after tot memory... " +  Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println(" after free memory... " +  Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    System.out.println(" after memory used ... " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()));
   // System.out.println(" weak reference " + wr.get());
```

When I run  the above code, I can see the free memory is 361064(In my system, however this value may vary)

But when I run the above code with System.gc() and comment list=null , I can see my free memory is coming(160944 in this case) less than the above test case. In both the scenarios, the objects are removed from memory.But why these values are different.

Comment: `new String("hello")` creates two objects. This constructor should be never use. Try `list.add("hello")`

Comment: @ajozwik I wouldn't say 'never'. There are valid use-cases for it. That's why it exists.

Answer (score 1):

**list = null;** nullifying any reference will automatically cause to be garbage collected. When you comment this line, the reference **list** is still active, then even if you call **System.gc()** it will not be garbage collected.

When you call **gc()** explicitly, the references which are already nullified or the which are out of scope are only be garbage collected.

Comment: if that is the case, what is the use of System.gc(). in which scenarios,it can be really used.:) Also, if list = null commented and run the application, what System.gc() call does because it frees or releases something

Comment: @UNNI gc() will free all those references which are nullified or out of scope. It will never clear those references which are active.

Comment: in the above test case when you run only with System.gc(), it frees some memory or some "value".In this case , what is THAT value is released because the list is still active,it will not be gced.

Comment: @UNNI System.gc() will of course frees some memory which cannot be referenced in your code. i think you need to read some article on garbage collector, google it or see http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html

Comment: why it is freeing some memory always (or atleast in this case)? not able to find perfect reasoning for this, though:)

Comment: @UNNI have you read the article? Read it, you will understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

GC works by looking at all of the objects in memory in order to find any `objects which are no longer being referenced` in the program. These unused objects can be deleted in order to make room for new memory objects.

So if any object is still being referred can not be garbage collected even if you call `System.gc()`. How can an object be garbage collected if you can refer it in your code?

By calling `list = null` the object that was being referred by `list` variable can't be referred again, so it is eligible to get garbage collected.